# Laravel Hyn Tenancy routes not defined on scheduler tasks

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I am using [Hyn Tenancy](https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant) to handle multiple tenants on our Laravel application. Every tenant routes are defined at `routes/tenants.php` as specified by the package documentation and the system is working smoothly as expected.

But when I try to access tenant route via scheduler task, `route not defined` error pops up. I have setup tenant appropriately on the job execution and everything except route are working fine.

Find detailed issue [here](https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant/issues/849)

Answer (score -1):

Try to give name to the routes like below:

```
Route::get('/register', function () {
return view('register');
})->name('register');
```

Then call the route with the name.